# Django-filter error: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am working with Django REST framework and django-filters and and I'd like to use the reverse relationship `annotation_set` as one of filters for a `GET` API that uses the model `Detection`.
The models are the following:

```
class Detection(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="detections/images")

    def local_image_path(self):
        return os.path.join('images' f"{self.id}.jpg")


class Annotation(models.Model):
    detection = models.ForeignKey(Detection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The serializer is:

```
class DetectionSerializer(UniqueFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    local_image_path = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Detection
        fields = '__all__'
```

And the viewset is:

```
class DetectionTrainingViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
    ):
    queryset = Detection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DetectionSerializer
    filterset_fields = ('annotation_set__id', )

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False)
    def list_ids(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        return Response(filtered_queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

When I make a call to the endpoint, I get the error:

```
'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: annotation_set__id
```

Shouldn't the field exist?
Note: I tried to add other fields to the `Annotation` model and then use `annotation_set__newfield` but I still have the error. I can confirm that the `newfield` exists because it is correctly serialized and return by the API when I comment out the line that set the `filterset_fields`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had to explicitly state the name of the reverse relationship:

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    detection = models.ForeignKey(Detection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='annotation_set')
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

If anybody knows why, I'd love to know it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the django filter docs, you may have missed a reference to DjangoFilterBackend, eg

```
queryset = Detection.objects.all()
serializer_class = DetectionSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filterset_fields = ('annotation_set__id', )
```

(see: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already set it as a general parameter in the app settings

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had similar problem it worked for me.
In your view file change the filterset_fields to the following.

```
class DetectionTrainingViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
queryset = Detection.objects.all()
serializer_class = DetectionSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filterset_fields = ('annotation__id', )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).